# calling the dll from jna that has dependencies on other dll

Tags: c, dll, jna, libxml2

I have made a dll which includes functions that parses the xml using libxml2 and this dll includes library of libxml2, zlib, iconv and require their respective libraries also. I have used _stdcall to export function my dll and now when i am accessing the functions from my dll the in jna then error " exeception in thread 'main" , java.lang.unsatisfied.error , unable to load parser.dll "

please suggest what to do

regards
priya

Comment: What have *you* tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: hi i have resolved this issue now using _cdecl now instead of _stdcall . I think the issue may be due to the system architecture.